# routerlink duplicating path in url

Tags: angular

I have the below route setup:

```
export const appRoutes:Routes = [
{ path: 'application/:id', component: ApplicationEditComponent, resolve: {applicationdropdowns: ApplicationEditResolver}},
{ path: 'application', component: ApplicationListComponent, resolve: {applications: ApplicationListResolver, applicationStatus: ApplicationstatusResolver}},
{ path: '', redirectTo: '/application', pathMatch: 'full'}
```

];

from the http://localhost:4200/application page, i built an href using:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/application', application?.applicationSeqid]">click here</a>
```

When I hover over the link i see:
localhost:4200/application/1

but when I click it, the resolver triggers, but then i see the below error in my console:

> Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment:
>   'application/application/1'

It appears to be adding an additional 'application' in the route, this only happens when i use the resolver.

I can manually hit the page by going to the url and it seems fine.  Also if i remove the resolver the link from the application page works fine.  my resolver is below:

```
@Injectable()
export class ApplicationEditResolver implements Resolve<any> {
    constructor(private _dropDownService : ApplicationDropdownService) { }

  resolve(){
    return this._dropDownService.getApplicationDropdowns().map(data => {
      let applicationDropdowns = <IApplicationDropdown>{};
      applicationDropdowns.applicationStatuses = data[0];
      applicationDropdowns.applicationTypes = data[1];
      return applicationDropdowns;
    });
  }
}
```

The dropdown service is supposed to return data from 2 api calls, i wanted to load them both in the resolver:

```
  getApplicationDropdowns():Observable<IApplicationDropdown> {
    return Observable.forkJoin([
      this.getApplicationStatus().map(res => res),
      this.getApplicationType().map(res => res)
    ]);
```

Comment: Post a complete minimal example reproducing the issue in a stackblitz.

Comment: I think your code problem to use resolve for two like path `'application/:id'` and `'application'` . Why are you use resolve for path `'application'`?

Comment: I had application for a list of applications, so i changed that to 'applications', now i'm getting the following error when i click on a link Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'applications/application/1'
it seems to keep applications always, the resolver does hit a breakpoint so it is going in there, but right after it runs that error comes up.  Also tried adding a base href to index, same results.

Comment: I found the issue, i had two links in the same area both going to the same route. 
 one on a div and the other within the div, clicking the inner was triggering both.  I had forgotten to remove the outer one when i put the inner one in, removing one solved the issue.